# Laravel5: Middleware or Validation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a form which holds a `url` input and I need to validate that the given URL is not blacklisted by a 3rd party API, i'm not sure if I need to use a `Middleware` or create a specific form `Request` and verify that URL before passing on that request to a command. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a job for Validator. Add your custom rule before validation:

```php
Validator::extend('custom', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    // make 3rd party request using $value

    if (…) {
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Don't forget to add error message string to `resourses/lang/xx/validation.php` file.

Read more: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 0):

Form validation doesn't belong in middleware. So it is better to create a form request class.

You probably need a custom validation rule. See limonte's answer.